# How to check that all non-blank cells in range have same value?

Tags: excel

I'm trying to determine whether all non-blank cells in a range have the same value.

This range should return TRUE:

```
45A
45A

45A
45A
```

This range should return FALSE:

```
45A
45B

45A
45A
```

If the range is blank, it should also return TRUE.

Following [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12049549/619177), I tried this:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(1/COUNTIF(L68:L72,L68:L72))=1
```

This works successfully when every cell in the range has a value, but if there are any blank cells in the range, I get a `#DIV/0!` error.  How can I make this work if there are blank cells?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adjust the numerator of your *count unique* to check for non-blanks and add a zero-length string to the `COUNTIFS`'s criteria arguement.

```
=SUMPRODUCT((L68:L72<>"")/COUNTIF(L68:L72,L68:L72&""))=1
```

See [Count Unique with SUMPRODUCT() Breakdown](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/wiki/office_2003-excel/count-unique-with-sumproduct-breakdown/1bc18979-4172-4537-993e-3897f74d6a5b) for more information.

Answer (score 2):

Another way is to suppress the error using `IFERROR` but you'll have to enter it as `array formula` by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>.

`=SUMPRODUCT(IFERROR(1/COUNTIF(L68:L72,L68:L72),0))=1`