# How to get WorksheetFunction.SumProduct() value to match =SUMPRODUCT()?

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to use SUMPRODUCT to determine whether all non-blank values in a range are the same.  I was able to get this to work as an Excel formula using [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28667001/619177), and now I want to get the result in VBA by using `WorksheetFunction.SumProduct()`.

I tried the following:

```
Public Function onlyOneValue(sheet As Worksheet) As Boolean

Dim sumProduct As Variant
Dim rng As Range
Dim rngAddress As String
Dim sumProductString As String
Dim column As Long

    Set rng = sheet.Range(sheet.Cells(5,20), _
                        sheet.Cells(65,20))
    rngAddress = rng.address
    sumProductString = "(" & rngAddress & "<>"""")/countif(" & _
                                            rngAddress & "," & rngAddress & "&"""")"
    sumProduct = WorksheetFunction.sumProduct(Evaluate(sumProductString))
    onlyOneValue = sumProduct = 1
End If

End Function
```

When I test with a column where all non-blank values are the same, the value of `sumProduct` is `1.63934426229508E-02`, but when I copy `sumProductString` into a `=SUMPRODUCT()` formula on the worksheet, I get the expected value of `1`.

If I don't use `Evaluate()` and instead use:

```
WorksheetFunction.sumProduct(sumProductString)
```

then I get this error:

```
Unable to get the SumProduct property of the WorksheetFunction class
```

How can I implement this function in VBA?

Comment: hi, if checking cell values is your only goal why don't you only compare values instead of sum product?

Comment: Something is really wrong with `sumProductString = "(" & rngAddress & "<>"""")/countif(" & _
                                            rngAddress & "," & rngAddress & "&"""")"`. Did an `Typename` on its `Evaluate` and it returned an error.

Comment: What do you mean by `SumProductString` shouldn't be an array or something? the `Sumproduct` method is given you a mismatch error because the argument type is not compatible with its parameters type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It worked for me when I added the `SUMPRODUCT` into the `Evaluate` and adjusted the *(* ie:

```
Public Function onlyOneValue(sheet As Worksheet) As Boolean

Dim rng As Range
Dim rngAddress As String
Dim sumProductString As String

    Set rng = sheet.Range(sheet.Cells(5, 20), _
                        sheet.Cells(65, 20))
    rngAddress = rng.Address
    sumProductString = "=SUMPRODUCT((" & rngAddress & "<>"""")/countif(" & _
                                            rngAddress & "," & rngAddress & "&""""))"

    onlyOneValue = (CLng(Evaluate(sumProductString)) = 1)

End Function
```

Comment: I guess he missed an "("?